# Access function outside of current component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I`m trying to access a function inside main.js with a button in  navbar.js so i can open a drawer which I have inside the main.js component.
Is there a way to do this? Or do i have to use Redux for this?
app.js

```
<Navbar />
<main />
```

navbar.js

```
<Button type="default" onClick={showDrawer}>Send</Button>
```

main.js

```
const showDrawer = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Pass it down as props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `showDrawer` function in `main.js` from `navbar.js`, you can pass the function as a prop to `navbar.js` and then call it within the `onClick` event of the button.

Code:

```js
// main.js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const showDrawer = () => {
  setOpen(true)
}

return (
  <div>
    <Navbar showDrawer={showDrawer} />
  </div>
)
```

```js
// navbar.js
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const { showDrawer } = props

  return (
    <Button type='default' onClick={showDrawer}>
      Send
    </Button>
  )
}
```

### Edit:

Based on your comment you can use React.memo to wrap the Navbar component:

```js
// main.js
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const showDrawer = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

return (
  <div>
    <Navbar showDrawer={showDrawer} />
  </div>
);
```

```js
// App.js
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(App);
```

Comment: But will this not display Navbar a second time since it is already being imported into App.js?
<Navbar showDrawer={showDrawer} />

Comment: It's not clear from the information provided where `Navbar` is being imported or how it is being used in `App.js`. In general, if `Navbar` is being imported and rendered in `App.js`, then it will be displayed in the rendered output

Comment: If you only want to display `Navbar` once, you can use the `React.memo` higher-order component to wrap the `Navbar` component in `App.js`. This will prevent the component from re-rendering if its props have not changed